# Error: No grammar constraints (DTD or XML Schema) referenced in the document

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I'm writing an XSD Schema for a XML Document. However, I get a warning that says:

> No grammar constraints (DTD or XML Schema) referenced in the document.

I'm attaching the beginnings of my XML and XSD documents where I do the reference. Any advice would be helpful.

XML:

```
<InvoiceList xmlns:p="https://www.example.org/StefansNamespace"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.example.org/StefansNamespace Aufgabe3XMLSchema.xsd">
```

XSD:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns="https://www.example.org/StefansNamespace"
           targetNamespace="https://www.example.org/StefansNamespace"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`InvoiceList` as written in your XML file is in **no namespace**.  To place it in the target namespace of your XSD (`https://www.example.org/StefansNamespace`), add the `p` namespace prefix to `InvoiceList`,

```
<p:InvoiceList xmlns:p="https://www.example.org/StefansNamespace"
 ^^
```

or use a default namespace:

```
<InvoiceList xmlns="https://www.example.org/StefansNamespace"
             ^^^^^
```